# Which Google API's require that you impersonate a user and which require that you do not?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Using a service key: In the Gmail API, for example, I must impersonate the user to access their email. To access their calendar, however, I get an “error: unauthorized client” unless I remove the line impersonating the user. I then have to instead go to Calendar and share that calendar with the service account. Why? Surely, if I'm impersonating a user then they have access to their own calendars.

Comment: Are you sure that the scopes are properly authorized? At code, at the API project console and at the ManageOauthClients page in the Google Apps admin console.

Comment: @AMS During my tests I've been using my personal account, it's not a Google Apps account. This is going to be used at my work, where we do have an Apps account, but I was hoping it would work either way in case I use it in the future in a scenario without one.

Comment: I don't get how you use a Service Account to impresonate a personal account. Are you allowed to impersonate a personal account with no prompt (It's a Service Account, right?) ? To be clear: you can definitely impersonate a Google Apps account to access its calendar if given the authorization.

Comment: @AMS Well, I don't remember if I saw this documented somewhere or just figured out, but as far as I can tell you can 'impersonate' the account that created the service account, i.e., my personal account; in production it will be our company's primary account.